# Assign UV map to each time frame of one moving object

Tags: animation, uv

Hello Blender Community,

I'm very new to Blender and I am trying to use Blender for visualizations of scientific data. Therefore, I visualized the data in Paraview and exported each time step as .ply-file. Using the Stop-motion-OBJ addon I am able to import all time steps into Blender. Then, according to https://blenderartists.org/t/rendering-a-video-of-point-clouds-imported-from-ply-files/533338 I obtain a video of point clouds from the said .ply-files. Afterwards, I used the CubeSurfer addon to mesh the points of my point cloud to an isosurface. Now, I want to assign a texture using the Poliigon Material Converter Addon to this mesh. However, I am encountering an issue regarding the UV maps. I need to assign an UV map to each frame of my generated mesh, since the mesh is changing over time. However, as soon as I've assigned an UV map to a frame of my video and jump to the next frame of the video in order to again assign an UV map, the UV map of the previous frame gets lost and hence I loose the texture of the previous frame. So my question is: How do I assign a UV map to each time frame of my object that is moving in time, in order to have a texture that moves with the moving object and appears during the whole movie?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: UV map creation is usually a manual process that can be tedious and time-consuming except for very simple shapes. A few questions/suggestions:
* Why do you need UV maps? Could you use procedural textures instead?
* The PLY file format supports per-vertex colors. Are you able to store color data on the vertices?